# What does CultureInfo.InvariantCulture mean?

Tags: .net, resharper

I have a string of text like so:

```
var foo = "FooBar";
```

I want to declare a second string called `bar` and make this equal to first and fourth character of my first `foo`, so I do this like so:

```
var bar = foo[0].ToString() + foo[3].ToString();
```

This works as expected, but [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper) is advising me to put `Culture.InvariantCulture` inside my brackets, so this line ends up like so:

```
var bar = foo[0].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        + foo[3].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What does this mean, and will it affect how my program runs?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492449/is-int32-tostring-culture-specific

Comment: For those looking for the 5 second answer: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture means "I don't care, I don't want culture involved in the first place. Now let me use the dumb thing."

Comment: @Andrew Can you rewrite all of MS' docs, pls?

Comment: @Yatrix Yeah, sure thing. I'd love to! Who's paying?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Not all cultures use the same format for dates and decimal / currency values.

This will matter for you when you are converting input values *(read)* that are stored as strings to  `DateTime`, `float`, `double` or `decimal`.  It will also matter if you try to format the aforementioned data types to strings *(write)* for display or storage.

If you know what specific culture that your dates and decimal / currency values will be in ahead of time, you can use that specific `CultureInfo` property (i.e. `CultureInfo("en-GB")`). For example if you expect a user input.

**The `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` property is used if you are formatting or parsing a string that should be parseable by a piece of software independent of the user's local settings.**

*The default value is `CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture` so the default CultureInfo is depending on the executing OS's settings. This is why you should always make sure the culture info fits your intention (see [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14418644/2822719) for a good guideline).*

- [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture Example](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/archive/2007/09/16/avoidcommonglobalizationerrors.aspx)
- [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583362/how-to-convert-string-to-double-with-proper-cultureinfo)
- [CultureInfo.InvariantCulture MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Predefined CultureInfo Names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: "en-US" though, I think it may actually depend on your system settings.

Comment: The default value isn't `en-US`. It's the local culture. And `InvariantCulture` is used when you want culture neutral formatting that's independent of the local system. For example when working with text based file formats.

Comment: To add to @CodesInChaos comment: The claim that _The default value is CultureInfo("en-US")_ is simply wrong. Also, the statement _The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture property is used when you aren't sure ahead of time what culture format your dates and decimal / currency values will be in._ is confusing. Using either the current, the invariant or a specific culture is something that should be a conscious decision, and if you get it wrong you can alienate your (non-US) users. You shouldn't use the invariant culture if you are "unsure". You need to be sure ahead of time.

Comment: -1 due to the issues mentioned in other comments. The answer by Martin is more helpful because it tells you when to use and not use each culture.

Comment: "if you are working exclusively in American English, then you don't need to worry about it.": Incorrect, you may be working exclusively in American English, but the software may run on a "en-GB" or a "de-DE" server, then it will make a difference, plus it can take the client's culture (if you say so in the web.config file), and that might not be "en-US" either...

Comment: Saved my project. THank you

Answer (score 192):

When numbers, dates and times are formatted into strings or parsed from strings a culture is used to determine how it is done. E.g. in the dominant `en-US` culture you have these string representations:

- 1,000,000.00 - one million with a two digit fraction
- 1/29/2013 - date of this posting

In my culture (`da-DK`) the values have this string representation:

- 1.000.000,00 - one million with a two digit fraction
- 29-01-2013 - date of this posting

In the Windows operating system the user may even customize how numbers and date/times are formatted and may also choose another culture than the culture of his operating system. The formatting used is the choice of the user which is how it should be.

So when you format a value to be displayed to the user using for instance `ToString` or `String.Format` or parsed from a string using `DateTime.Parse` or `Decimal.Parse` the default is to use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. This allows the user to control the formatting.

However, a lot of string formatting and parsing is actually not strings exchanged between the application and the user but between the application and some data format (e.g. an XML or CSV file). In that case you don't want to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` because if formatting and parsing is done with different cultures it can break. In that case you want to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` (which is based on the `en-US` culture). This ensures that the values can roundtrip without problems.

The reason that ReSharper gives you the warning is that some application writers are unaware of this distinction which may lead to unintended results but they never discover this because  their `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is `en-US` which has the same behavior as `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. However, as soon as the application is used in another culture where there is a chance of using one culture for formatting and another for parsing the application may break.

So to sum it up:

- Use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (the default) if you are formatting or parsing a user string.
- Use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` if you are formatting or parsing a string that should be parseable by a piece of software.
- Rarely use a specific national culture because the user is unable to control how formatting and parsing is done.

Comment: In regards to the last point, "Rarely use a specific national culture...", would currency formatting be an exception? For example, if I have a `Decimal` variable containing a certain value in US Dollars, would I want to make an exception and use `en-US` as culture when displaying it to make sure I don't get a result that looks like a number in Euros? [I tried](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WYpIvw) `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, but got this for the currency marker `¤`, so I'm not sure that's the right way.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: My advice is just general advice and may not apply to your specific case. However, I would think that the way you display the decimal point (comma or dot) should be something that the user controls (e.g. use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`). If you in addition to displaying a number need the currency then perhaps you should do that in a consistent manner, i.e. not using a `CultureInfo` and instead use the three letter currency code like `USD 1,234.56`. Then you don't get into the problems of mapping a currency to a culture.

Comment: Here's a catch: InvariantCulture depends on the os and is therefore not constant. If you have two instances of your software on different os, you should not use InvariantCulture to exchange strings between the two instances. Instead, you need to define a constant culture.

Comment: @user74696c can u pls elaborate on ur catch? (with reference if possible?)
What you are saying - would not that have the opposite effect - of making InvariantCulture the most brittle (variable) across applications instead of making it agnostic

Comment: @gawkface: I may have misread the answer by JohnB saying "The default value is CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture so the default CultureInfo is depending on the executing OS's settings.", thinking it says the default value of Invariantculture depends on OS. I ran into a problem when my csv files turned out different with InvariantCulture on Windows 10 German and Windows Server 2016 English. But maybe I had a different bug there.

Comment: @gawkface The accepted answer is not the right one if you ask me (check the comments and downvotes if they are visible to you). It's been edited to remove some of the invalid information but new invalid information like the quote that you mention has been added. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is a fixed culture and it doesn't vary depending on the OS. I believe that there have been bugs/unexpected things around cultures when comparing Windows and Linux but I would be surprised if `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` has been affected by these.

Comment: thanks @user74696c and Martin Liversage for the follow-ups. Will keep this information in-mind

Answer (score 39):

According to Microsoft:

> The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture property is neither a neutral nor a
> specific culture. It is the third type of culture that is
> culture-insensitive. It is associated with the English language but
> not with a country or region.

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4c5zdc6a(vs.71).aspx)

So InvariantCulture is similair to culture "en-US" but not exactly the same. If you write:

```
var d = DateTime.Now;
var s1 = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   // "05/21/2014 22:09:28"
var s2 = d.ToString(new CultureInfo("en-US"));       // "5/21/2014 10:09:28 PM"
```

then s1 and s2 will have a similar format but InvariantCulture adds leading zeroes and "en-US" uses AM or PM.

So InvariantCulture is better for internal usage when you e.g save a date to a text-file or parses data. And a specified CultureInfo is better when you present data (date, currency...) to the end-user.

Comment: I ran your example code to confirm: InvariantCulture uses American MM/dd/yyyy rather than following the ISO 8601 year-goes-first format. Despite that it's intended for portable storage and mechanical processing, rather than for human consumption. How confusing

Answer (score 6):

JetBrains offer a reasonable [explanation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/Specify+a+culture+in+string+conversion+explicitly),

> "Ad-hoc conversion of data structures to text is largely dependent on
>   the current culture, and may lead to unintended results when the code
>   is executed on a machine whose locale differs from that of the
>   original developer. To prevent ambiguities, ReSharper warns you of any
>   instances in code where such a problem may occur."

but if I am working on a site I know will be in English only, I just ignore the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

For things like numbers (decimal points, commas in amounts), they are usually preferred in the specific culture.

A appropriate way to do this would be set it at the culture level (for German) like this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat = new CultureInfo("de").NumberFormat;
```