# Mysql Workbench - Insert number with comma in DOUBLE => Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a database with DOUBLE fields.

I can't insert number like 19,50, ...

But 19.50 works...

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change decimal separator in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql)

Comment: The SQL standard specifies `.` as the decimal separator. Using `,` isn't possible in MySQL.

Comment: You have the answer in your question :D

Answer (score 0):

[Parse strings to double with comma and point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560465/parse-strings-to-double-with-comma-and-point) might give you a few suggestions. I'm assuming here the comma number is a string.