# Double.Parse cannot keep comma

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert a string into double, I've this value: `53.095` and try to convert into double as:

```
string doub = "53.095";
var cv = Convert.ToDouble(doub);
```

I get: `53095`. Why I doesn't get the comma? What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe this SO question could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560465/parse-strings-to-double-with-comma-and-point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess it's because different countries handle comma differently. My country, for example uses `,` instead. So you must be aware of how the string is formatted.

```
string doub = "53.095";
var cv = double.Parse(doub, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

For another localization this will work.

```
string doub = "53,095"; // note ,
var cv = double.Parse(doub, new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
```

**EDIT:**

As [king_nak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345027/king-nak) mentioned, you will be able to use [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) as long as you're using the english style for formatting.

> [...] it is associated with the English language but not with any
>   country/region.

```
string doub = "53.095";
string doub2 = "53,095"; 
var cv1 = double.Parse(doub, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Works
var cv2 = double.Parse(doub2, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Does not work.
```

Comment: I suggest using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of a new info for GB-en

Comment: @king_nak, yes that is indeed an alternative. However, depending on the server that's executing the code it may not be what you want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean

Comment: @smoksnes According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx , `InvariantCulture` is associated with the english language. That would be save if you know your input is formatted like this.

Comment: I think you mean `"en-GB"` (English, United Kingdom) and `"sv-SE"` (Swedish, Sweden). _Edit:_ `"GB-en"` becomes __Unknown Locale (gb-EN)__.

Comment: @king_nak, I stand corrected. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, thank you. I've updated my answer.