# I can not write the decimal number in the textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, decimal

I have a c # program that uses ten computers.Program gets decimal numbers as input. The problem is that the input is written as 10.5, on some computers, however, the program takes this comma as a dot. I do not understand why. I converted the commas to dots using the "replace" command in the program. Now, neither comma nor dot is written to get a decimal input in the problem computers. As an example, I share the following codes

At first, my code was like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
    decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox2.Text);
    decimal result = number1 + number2;
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
}
```

Then on some computers I noticed that the program recognizes the comma key used to write decimal numbers as dot.I do not know why.

I used the "replace" command to convert the commas in the number to dots.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text1 = textBox1.Text.Replace(".", ",");
    string text2 = textBox2.Text.Replace(".", ",");
    decimal number1 = Convert.ToDecimal(text1);
    decimal number2 = Convert.ToDecimal(text2);
    decimal result = number1 + number2;
    textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
}
```

It works right on my computer. On some computers, the program does not detect the dot when number is written using a  dot. On some computers, neither point nor comma is detected by the program.

I want all the computers to be able to write decimal numbers. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse strings to double with comma and point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560465/parse-strings-to-double-with-comma-and-point)

Answer (score 3):

Use this to be independent from PC's reginal settings:

```
str = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", d); // decimal to string
d = decimal.Parse(str, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // string to decimal
```

Comment: Which library is needed for this? The parameters in parentheses give an error.

Comment: @Alihan AYDIN: add `using System.Globalization;` among other `using` for `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` argument

Answer (score 1):

It is because of different culture settings. Some resources like the current time and language are retrieved by the application from the device at runtime. When it comes to decimals, some countries write them with a period sign, and some countries write them with comma's.

When it comes to parsing and printing, you can usually pass a culture setting as a parameter (you can do this with comma's, I'm sure). If you pass a culture setting, it will override the default setting (which is defined by the device the app runs on).

If you don't want to pass a culture every time you do something with decimals, you should be able to set the culture application wide:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(theCultureString); //e.g. "en-US"
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```

Note how this sets the culture for a current thread. If you're working on a non-main thread, this obviously doesn't work. If you set this for the main thread, and then create a new thread off of it, the new thread should copy the main thread's culture.

Comment: there is no "CultureInfo" in my c#. There is "CultureInfoConverter".

Comment: What framework are you using? CultureInfo should be available in the System.Globalization package in the .NET Framework, maybe you need to add a reference?

Comment: @AlihanAYDIN Click on `CultureInfo`, hold Shift+Alt and press F10. This will open menu which `using` is necessary to add in C# file.