# Inconsistent DateTime to Unix Time conversion and error on 24 hour input

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, unix-timestamp, dst

Attached is a method I am currently using that takes in a list of `DateTime` strings, their input format (i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`), and their offset in the form of hours.

As for the culture and "standard", I am using `InvariantCulture` and I am converting the times to `UTC`.

```
    public int unixFormat3(string dateTimeInput, string inputFormat, int hours)
    {
        DateTime result;
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, provider);

        int unixTime = (Int32)(result.ToUniversalTime().AddHours(hours).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc))).TotalSeconds;
        return unixTime;
    }
```

Two issues with said method:

1. I am using this website as a comparison. If my input is `2014-03-18 21:00:00`, my output, according to my method, is `1395190800`, which converts back to `2014-03-19 01:00:00`. It has a four hour difference. The desired output is this:

[image]

2. If my input is `2014-03-18 24:00:00`, I get this error:

`The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.`

Noticeably, it does not allow the input of `24` in the `HH` part. This is a weird error as `NodaTime` handles it just fine... Though that's irrelevant as I am using `DateTime`.

Does anyone have any insight on this area?

EDIT:

Upon some experimentation, removing the `.ToUniversalTime()` removes my 4-hour offset.. Why is this happening?

```
public int unixFormat3(string dateTimeInput, string inputFormat, int hours)
{
    DateTime result;
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, provider);

    int unixTime = (Int32)(result.AddHours(hours).Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc))).TotalSeconds;
    return unixTime;
}
```

Comment: 3/19 00:00 won't work?

Comment: It does work, though `24:00` doesn't. It seems to the `DateTime` library, `24:00` and `00:00` are not the same thing.

Comment: Calling Jon Skeet and Matt Johnson :).

Answer (score 1):

This document, http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime, cited in this question [How to know whether a given string is a valid UTC DateTime format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718596/how-to-know-whether-a-given-string-is-a-valid-utc-datetime-format) does not list 24 as a valid hour value.

This document, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601, cited by an answer to the question does list 24:00 as a valid time.  This one, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight, also says 24:00 is valid.

Answer (score 1):

The `System.DateTime` object represents hours as an integer value between 0 and 23 (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.datetime.hour(v=vs.100).aspx). As far as I know, NodaTime doesn't use any of the .NET provided `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` classes and handles everything itself, which is why it's handling an hour of 24 correctly.

As for why `ToUniversalTime()` is adding an offset, its probably because the `ParseExact` is returning a date that's already been adjusted. (What is the value of `result` just before you call `ToUniversalTime()`?)

You may also want to change your call to use this overload of `ParseExact` instead:

```
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, provider, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

This tells the parser to assume the time is in UTC if no time zone is specified in the parsed string.

As a side note, you should probably declare your Unix epoch as a readonly global variable somewhere and use `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact`.

```
public class UnixTime
{
    public static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public int unixFormat3(string dateTimeInput, string inputFormat, int hours)
    {
        int unixTime = -1;
        DateTime result = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeInput, inputFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out result))
        {
            unixTime = (int)(result.AddHours(hours).Subtract(UnixTime.Epoch)).TotalSeconds;
        }

        return unixTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you SO much for the detailed answer. It was extremely informative. Could you give me a suggestion on what to do with C# not handling 24? That just seems so strange; I can imagine many scenarios where there would be a 24 as input.

Comment: With `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` http://puu.sh/7HUMD/2f48f7e43d.png. Without `ToUniversalTime()` or `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`: http://puu.sh/7HUUv/a6cf577df3.png It appears that when you don't assume/to UTC, the code doesn't offset for you. When you do assume UTC, it offsets for you. How exactly does it assume my offset? According to my computer and my timezone, my timezone is: `UTC -05:00`, not `-04:00`.

Comment: Wow. The more I learn about DateTimes and timezones, the more confused I am. Since the input is `2014-03-18 21:00:00`, it's timezone agnostic. It's ambiguous what timezone it is, because there's no locale or timezone tags. Do you assume that's UTC by default?

Comment: You should have `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal`.  Otherwise, the input is treated as universal, but it is then converted to *local*.

Comment: @MattJohnson, I updated the code to include `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal'. Thanks!

Comment: @theGreenCabbage You may be able to use the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method to see if it will parse into a date first. (In fact, you probably should be doing that anyway.) That will at least keep you from throwing an exception. It won't solve the 24 hour problem, so you'll probably have to do some parsing yourself if you want to handle that. As for the hour difference in time zone offsets, you may be hitting a daylight savings time issue. Under the hood, it's looking at a lot of different things to figure out your time zone offset, but a lot of it is based on the culture and TimeZoneInfo used.