# Calling Number.ToString() and always use the standard decimal point in any regional configuration?

Tags: c#

Lets suppose this in C#.

```
  double d = 5.555455;
  string s = d.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine(s);
```

The output is

```
5.555455
```

In my case my regional configuration is for "." as decimal separator.
The problem is that the computer's regional configuration sometimes is "," which makes the output to be:

```
5,555455
```

What I do need is to make sure that the number will be ALWAYS be converted to a string using "." as decimal and no "," as thousand separator.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [invariant culture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9760237/335858):

```
double d = 5.555455;
string s = d.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Among other things, this forces the dot `.` as the decimal separator.

Comment: Thank you very much. The number is added to a JSON as number. It failed to parse when request comming from certain machnes.