# DateTime.ToString removes slashes

Tags: c#

I want to have date as `02/03/2017` for 3 March 2017 in my mvc view.

With `DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")`  I just get `02 03 2017`. Why is my slashes going away?

Comment: No repro: http://ideone.com/7gioH2.

Comment: You can try `ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Slash in date time format represents culture-specific delimiter. For en culture that is still slash, but for russian culture for example it is dot ("."). For culture you use it seems to be a space. So if you want culture-specific format - better not escape slashes but pass appopriate culture to ToString method.

Comment: The slashes have a special meaning when it comes to parsing dates. It will be replaced with your current culture's date-separator. To avoid this you have to escape them like Dmitry has already shown or use `InvariantCulture` as second argument. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#The) at _"The "/" custom format specifier"_

Comment: What culture do you want to display the date in?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might need to provide a culture for your to string.

```
DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: this seems to do the trick. what does the `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` tell the method to do? What would happen if i run it in Russia as others have put forward as an example?

Comment: I think this posts sums up what it up:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9760339/3410616

if you do not provide the Culture property your application uses the default culture you have set on your computer or main application thread.

I hope I got the question right(in the comment). 

If I got your question right, you can mark my answer.

p.s. If you don't want to set the culture everytime, set the culture of your main thread (tho you will need to google how to do it. It's easy tho).

Answer (score 4):

*Escape* slashes:

```
 var result = MyDateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: Actually that's not "escaping" the slashes; that's just specifying a string using the "literal string delimiter". While this works, it may be more natural to use the escape character to actually escape the slashes: `MyDateTime.ToString("dd\\/MM\\/yyyy");` or `MyDateTime.ToString(@"dd\/MM\/yyyy");` - although you might argue this is less readable... ;)