# toLocaleDateString & toLocaleString, which method can instead both methods in .Net

Tags: javascript, .net

I wanna format short date for some locale, but it's different between JS and .NET, can I make it the same?
In JS, I use toLocaleDateString to format, and in .NET use ShortDatePattern, but it's not the same formating.
Ex:

JS :   `locate: Italian (Switzerland) => shortDate: 27/9/2020`
.NET: `locate: Italian (Switzerland) => shortDate: 27.09.2020`

Any ideal for it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you use this code 
 `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`
However, this bug is due to the operating system settings. This bug does not exist if you modify the date format.

Comment: this bug not only for one locale, I use it for many locale, so I hope we have a method which the same return in JS and .NET

Comment: in .NET reffer to backend in one server . and JS in client use this app.so if in server date format correctly .and is ok.in every where

Comment: answer edited.i help of [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42551949/datetime-tostring-removes-slashes)