# Format date string in a specific pattern

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a to display Date format in this format

> Tuesday April 17  6:12:02 2018

I have tried this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
        var day = today.Day;
        var month = today.Month;
        var year = today.Year;

        Console.WriteLine(today);
        Console.WriteLine(day);
        Console.WriteLine(month);
        Console.WriteLine(year);
        var answer = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
        Console.WriteLine(today);
    }
}
```

How can I get the Month and Day like Tuesday, Wednesday in full text , also can the date be changed to AM and PM... 
I can get the year and date in int.

Comment: You _really_ need to look into [string format patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).  Your entire problem can be solved in 1 line of code

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was taken from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) listed in the comments. You basically add in the string format patterns with the format you want to display. Notice there is a difference between uppercase and lowercase formats.

As Mentioned by [Soner Gönül](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882729/format-date-string-in-a-specific-pattern/49882836?noredirect=1#comment86783089_49882836), if you are targeting an audience to not be english based then consider adding in a `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` field to the `toString()`. That way the date displayed is not tied to a certain culture. Just don't forget to include `System.Globalization`.

From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Invariant culture data is stable over time and across installed cultures and cannot be customized by users. This makes the invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations that persist formatted data

```
var today = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

Console.WriteLine(today.ToString("dddd MMMM dd hh:mm:ss tt yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// Monday April 16 12:11:06 PM 2018 <- My time
```

Comment: Perfect  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: For the hour `6` to be output as `6` rather than `06` change the `hh` to `h`. `DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(1).ToString("dddd MMMM dd h:mm:ss tt yyyy")`

Comment: Be careful about culture! If your `CurrentCulture` is **not** "english-based", you can't get english day and month names as a result. That's why you should always consider to supply culture settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is a *classic* formatting question.

If you wanna get *textual* (aka string) representation of a `DateTime`, the most usual way is using [`ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2) with optional format and culture settings.

Your aimed string contains english-based month and day names. That's why you need to use an *english-based* culture setting like [`InvariantCulture`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9760237/447156).

And putting formats in your string, you just need to follow the rules on [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) page.

```
var answer = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("dddd MMMM dd h:mm:ss yyyy", 
                                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```