# Isn't CultureInfo.Invariant always supposed to be English Based?

Tags: .net-core, internationalization, cultureinfo

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-7.0&devlangs=csharp&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(SolutionItemsProject)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) on `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` states that it is associated with the English Language.  And [StackOverflow answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23801542/5869304) seem to agree.

So I expected that calling something like `DateTime.ToString` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the sole argument would be a safe way of always getting some English-looking date/time string.

But it does not appear to work that way.  When this C#/.NET 7.0 code of mine runs on a Japanese system

```
foreach (var l in Licenses)
    Log.Error($"\t{l.Feature}, Expires={l.Expires.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}");
```

(where `l.Expires` is a `DateTime`.)

I get log lines like this:

```
12:43:05.605 [  1] ERROR - IsLicensed:  Gsx.Application, Expires=一度も無い
```

Am I misunderstanding the meaning of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?`
If it is not meant to output the date in English, then what is its purpose?